# Find breakpoints in given permutation

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am doing text processing for a bioinformatics assignment where we have to separate sequences of numbers by increasing (+) or decreasing (-).

A **breakpoint** is where a sequence switches from + to - or vice versa. However, all numbers in the sequences have to be in order. It is possible for a sequence to consist of one number.

In other words, increasing strips can look like:

```
vector<-c("+1 +2 +3 +4 +5")  
vector<-c("+333 +334")
```

but NOT:

```
vector<-c("+1 +3 +4")
vector<-c("+333 +332")
```

The same logic applies for decreasing strips.

```
vector->c("-10 -9 -8")    NOT vector->("-10 -8 -7")
```

For the following example there are 8 breakpoints:

```
vector<-c("+3 +4 +5 -12 -8 -7 -6 +1 +2 +10 +9 -11 +13 +14")

#break1: +3 +4 +5
#break2: -12
#break3: -8 -7 -6
#break4: +1 +2 
#break5: +10
#break6: +9
#break7: -11
#break8: +13 +14
```

Is there any way of coding this in R? I tried earlier using:

```
vector<-c(3,4,5,12,8,7,6,1,2,10,9,11,13,14)
Strip<- vector[-1] - head(vector, -1)
table(Strip)


#-5 -4 -1  1  2  7  8 
#1  1  3  4  2  1  1
```

acorrding to that resulting table, I only had 7 breakpoints (3+4=7 on the bottom row) I could only get this code to look at the vector if there were no +/- characters.  For that reason this code doesn't count +10 and +9 as separate breaking points because their order is not taken into consideration. Only their distance (1) is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the pluses and minuses all seem to work well with positive integer flow, I'll try this:

```
vec <- "+3 +4 +5 -12 -8 -7 -6 +1 +2 +10 +9 -11 +13 +14"
```

First, we can split this by spaces into individual strings:

```
(splvec <- strsplit(vec, "\\s+")[[1]])
#  [1] "+3"  "+4"  "+5"  "-12" "-8"  "-7"  "-6"  "+1"  "+2"  "+10" "+9"  "-11"
# [13] "+13" "+14"
```

(This can be extended to *not* hard-code `[[1]]`, I'll leave that as an exercise for now.) This is fine, but we want/need integers instead for easy comparison:

```
(splvec <- as.integer(strsplit(vec, "\\s+")[[1]]))
#  [1]   3   4   5 -12  -8  -7  -6   1   2  10   9 -11  13  14
```

Now, we need to group them by when they change from "increment by 1" and anything else:

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(splvec) != 1))
#  [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 8
```

This provides easy grouping information, which we will feed into `split` (which creates a `list` by group):

```
str( split(splvec, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(splvec) != 1))) )
# List of 8
#  $ 1: int [1:3] 3 4 5
#  $ 2: int -12
#  $ 3: int [1:3] -8 -7 -6
#  $ 4: int [1:2] 1 2
#  $ 5: int 10
#  $ 6: int 9
#  $ 7: int -11
#  $ 8: int [1:2] 13 14
```

And if you absolutely must have it formatted as before (single string per run of pos/neg ints), then:

```
str( lapply(split(splvec, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(splvec) != 1))),
            function(a) paste(sprintf('%+d', a), collapse = ' ')) )
# List of 8
#  $ 1: chr "+3 +4 +5"
#  $ 2: chr "-12"
#  $ 3: chr "-8 -7 -6"
#  $ 4: chr "+1 +2"
#  $ 5: chr "+10"
#  $ 6: chr "+9"
#  $ 7: chr "-11"
#  $ 8: chr "+13 +14"
```

(I stepped through things for demonstration, it can easily be streamlined.)

Comment: thank you for your response! for some reason it doesn't work with data sets this big??
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iknQK2pGN1wol--bbYrnTdTtpOLXNqk1JfAnKM81ZDc/edit?usp=sharing) 
 the result for this one should be 178

Comment: I normally don't do this, Gabriel, but I downloaded that file, ran the code, and got 179. I dove a little deeper, and the closest gap from the last of a group to the first of the next group is 342. I suggest that either (a) there is a rule/constraint I have mis-interpreted, or (b) 178 is incorrect. Unfortunately, to get to the bottom of this, you will need to compare group-by-group with some answer key to see what is actually incorrect about this implementation.

Comment: Any progress, Gabriel? It'd be nice to provide some closure to the question, perhaps to either update the rules (and therefore better inform the code) or whatever.

Comment: I️ forgot to mark this as answered, my bad. I️t turns out my issues with the dataset I️ provided you with were due to copying and pasting issues on my machine. I️ appreciate your time and help on this!

Comment: Especially with something that large (and in a google doc file), that doesn't surprise me. Glad it worked (and that I followed the rules correctly!).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to the provided solution:

Firstly, this is the input `v <- c("+3 +4 +5 -12 -8 -7 -6 +1 +2 +10 +9 -11 +13 +14")`. I then proceeded to clean the string from all numbers:

```
zeichen <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\d", "", v), split = " "))
zeichen
[1] "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "-" "+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "+" "+"
```

Now, we define a `mapping` which will transform `+ to 1; - to -1`:

```
mapping <- function(x){
  if(x == "+"){return(1)}
  if(x == "-"){return(-1)}
}
helper <- vapply(zeichen, mapping, numeric(1))
helper
 +  +  +  -  -  -  -  +  +  +  +  -  +  + 
 1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1
```

Finally, we consider the differences of `helper`:

```
delta <- diff(helper)
delta
 +  +  -  -  -  -  +  +  +  +  -  +  + 
 0  0 -2  0  0  0  2  0  0  0 -2  2  0
```

Wherever `delta == -2`, there is a break point from `+` to `-` and the other way around where `delta == 2`.

Now, we also need to consider the instances where the breakpoints due to the numbering (e.g. `+10;+9`):

```
# we create a vector w which contains the numeric data of v
w <- as.numeric(gsub("^\\d", "", v))
delta2 <- diff(w) # wherever delta2 is not 1, there is a breakpoint
```

Here we determine the (indices of the) breakpoints:

```
breakpoints <- sort(union(which(delta != 0), which(delta2 != 1)))
breakpoints
 -  +  -  + 
 3  7 11 12
```

And finally, one can save the different arrays in a list (there is a multitude of ways to do it at this point):

```
# firstly, we want v to be a vector
v <- unlist(strsplit(v, split = " "))
# now we declare our list
mylist <- rep(list(NA), length(breakpoints) + 1)
for(i in 1:(length(breakpoints) + 1)){
  f <- ifelse(i > 1, breakpoints[i-1]+1, 0)
  l <- ifelse(i > length(breakpoints), length(v), breakpoints[i])
  mylist[[i]] <- v[f:l]
}
mylist
[[1]]
[1] "+3" "+4" "+5"

[[2]]
[1] "-12"

[[3]]
[1] "-8" "-7" "-6"

[[4]]
[1] "+1" "+2"

[[5]]
[1] "+10"

[[6]]
[1] "+9"

[[7]]
[1] "-11"

[[8]]
[1] "+13" "+14"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for your response! I found it doesn't work with data sets this big??
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iknQK2pGN1wol--bbYrnTdTtpOLXNqk1JfAnKM81ZDc/edit?usp=sharing) 
 the result for this one should be 178